# Syntax error within IF command

Tags: if-statement, syntax

```
print ('Here are the availible currency choices for today:')  
currencylist = ['US Dollar','Kenyan Shilling','Brazilian Real','Canadian 
Dollar','Indian Rupee','Philippine Peso','Indonesian Rupiah']  
print(*currencylist, sep='\n')  
currency= input(str('Which currency would you like to choose? '))  
pound= input(float('Please enter the amount you would like to exchange. £')  
if currency == ('US Dollar')  
    rate= 1.52  
    print rate
```

I keep getting a syntax error when I try and define the `rate` variable. Any ideas?

Comment: What language is this? Python? You should add a language-specific tag to your post. It looks like you're missing a `:` at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Assuming this is Python, please add a `python` tag to your post so it attracts the right people and we know for sure what language you're using.  Also, in the future, always post the error message.  But I bet it's just the missing colon.  If that's the case, please let us know in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` requires a colon at the end of the condition:

`if currency == 'US Dollar':
       rate = 1.52`

Answer (score 1):

you use this

```
if (currency == 'US Dollar')  {

    rate= 1.52  
    print rate
}
```

Comment: then use clone :